# How to show nsdate without converting to local time zone?

Tags: objective-c, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to present a date to the user in the dates own timezone. So without it being converted to the users timezone.

Basically what happens: I retrieve a string '2015-04-01T15:35:00-04:00' from the backend, and I convert it to a NSDate. Later on I want to show the user the time: **15:35**.

But NSDateFormatter converts the date to my system time zone (+02:00) which results in showing **21:35**.

I've searched all over the internet to find out I can skip this convert, but I can't find anything.

What do I miss?

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: NSDate represents an absolute value in time and has no knowledge of time zones. Once you have converted the string "2015-04-01T15:35:00-04:00" to an NSDate it is just stored as seconds since Jan 1, 2001 GMT.

Comment: Why don't you simply extract the substring "15:25" using NSString methods, without any NSDate conversion?

Comment: @MartinR That feels kinda hacky. I also need the full date to do some ordering stuff, it would force me to create extra properties to store data in.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to save the original timezone in addition to the `NSDate` representation and use it when you want to present the time in the original timezone.

`NSDate` keeps the date/time relative to GMT (UTC).

Comment: Can you provide an code example? I don't know how to create a NSTimezone object from ie. -04:00.

Comment: @NielsKoole [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(-4 * 3600)] ?